# Chrome extension: (DOM)Debugger API does not work anymore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, remote-debugging

Our chrome extension does not work correctly anymore since version 37.0.2062.103  (It used to work correctly on chrome version 36.0.1985.143).

Specifically, the debugger API has stopped working for us when we use the DOMDebugger.
See the attached code: (background.js)

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    if( changeInfo.status == "loading"  && tab.active){
        var debugId = {tabId:tabId};
        chrome.debugger.attach(debugId, '1.0', function() {
            chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debugId, 'Debugger.enable', {}, function() {
                chrome.debugger.sendCommand(debugId, "DOMDebugger.setEventListenerBreakpoint", {'eventName':'click'},
                    function(result) {
                        console.log('registering click');
                    });
            });
        });
    }
});
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
function onEvent(debuggeeId, method,params) {
    if(method=="Debugger.paused"){
        console.log('DONE!');
    }
};
```

The extension successfully starts the debugger. we get the yellow debugger ribbon.
We also see the 'registering click' msg in the console. the result argument is an empty object {} (line 8).
However upon clicking on a button that has a click event listener nothing happens.

It used to work without any issues.

Comment: Sounds like you should also file an issue on https://crbug.com and add a link to it here.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it regressed with https://codereview.chromium.org/305753005. One needs to call "DOM.enable" for it to work now. On the Chrome side, we should implicitly enable DOM domain upon setEventListenerBreakpoint for backwards compatibility. Unfortunately it already squeezed into the stable release.

Comment: Is there a bug regarding this? If yes, please add a link to it.