# Chrome extension: Debugger API does not fire event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to listen all timeline events that happened in tab,
I create an extension

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var tabId = tab.id;

    console.log("tabId = ", tabId);

    if (running === false) {
        checkAvailable();

        chrome.debugger.attach({
            tabId: tabId
        }, protocolVersion, function() {
            running = true;

            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                return;
            }

            chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: tabId
            }, "Tracing.start", { "maxCallStackDepth" : 5 }, function(response) {

                console.log(response);              
                // listening for responses from Timeline
                chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function(tabId, method, params) {
                    console.log("params = ", params);
                });
            });



            chrome.debugger.onDetach.addListener(function (source, reason) {
                running = false;
            });
        });        
    } else {
        chrome.debugger.detach({
            tabId: tabId
        }, null);
        running = false;
    }
});
```

After clicking an icon I could see yellow bar at the top of the page and message is "extension is debugging this page".

However, after F5 I do not see that my extension listen to timeline events.

It looks like event has not been assigned.

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function(tabId, method, params) {
    console.log("params = ", params);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764336/chrome-extension-domdebugger-api-does-not-work-anymore

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to send `Debugger.enable`:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
        { tabId: tabId }, "Debugger.enable", {}, () => {
```

before doing

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
                tabId: tabId
            }, "Tracing.start", { "maxCallStackDepth" : 5 }, function(response) {
```

Here is a working version:

```
let running = false
let protocolVersion = '1.3'

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  var tabId = tab.id;

  console.log("tabId = ", tabId);

  if (running === false) {
    /*    checkAvailable(); */

    chrome.debugger.attach({
      tabId: tabId
    }, protocolVersion, function () {
      running = true;

      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
      }


      chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
        { tabId: tabId }, "Debugger.enable", {}, () => {

        chrome.debugger.sendCommand({
          tabId: tabId
        }, "Tracing.start", { "maxCallStackDepth": 5 }, function (response) {

          console.log(response);
          // listening for responses from Timeline
          chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function (tabId, method, params) {
            console.log("params = ", params);
          });
        });

})

      chrome.debugger.onDetach.addListener(function (source, reason) {
        running = false;
      });
    });
  } else {
    chrome.debugger.detach({
      tabId: tabId
    }, null);
    running = false;
  }
});
```