# Chrome extension : Detect which script created an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to build an extension to show the page requests as a tree, using chrome.debugger.
I'd like to be able to assign as parent of a dynamic iframe, the script that created it, instead the frame where it's located.
To do that, i guess i'd need to insert a DOM breakpoint, using the DOMDebugger domain of the Chrome Debugging protocol,but i cant find any example on how to use the setEventListenerBreakpoint method.

With the following code:

```
chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
{tabId:currentTabId},'DOMDebugger.setEventListenerBreakpoint',{eventName:'subtree-modified'},function(a){
                console.dir(arguments);
            });
```

The callback is called just once, with an empty object as argument.

How should i use setEventListenerBreakpoint?

Comment: Not familiar about this field, but maybe `Debugger.enable` is needed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764336/chrome-extension-domdebugger-api-does-not-work-anymore

Comment: Generally, you can see the commands sent by the debugger while you perform the action in question manually by following the procedure described in the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol

Comment: Good tip, @wOxxOm ..Sniffing the protocol i was able to find out the right function i'd need to use (setDOMBreakpoint), and that requires getting the root node id (DOM.getDocument), and listening for 'subtree-modified' events..
The problem is, this event doesnt specify which actual modification has happened, or what node id was inserted in the document, so i have no way of knowing if it was an iframe, or something else.
So, i guess it's just not possible to do what i was looking for.

Comment: DOM.getDocument returns the document nodeId. With that, i can call setDOMBreakpoint (nodeId,'subtree-modification'), and it gets called.Then, i use Debugger.getBacktrace(), and i get all the information i need about the script.
What i dont get anywhere, is what the actual subtree modification is.I dont know if an iframe has been appended, or a div has been removed.

Comment: Welp, you'll have to use a normal content script for that with a MutationObserver attached on demand, it will report the changes via the background page.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, i've done it indirectly, using a different set of tools:
 - Getting each page request (event  "Network.requestWillBeSent" )
 - Getting each script in the page (event "Debugger.scriptParsed")

If a page request has an initiator, and there are stack frames available, i can get the script that it's causing that request.
If the request and the script belong to different frameIds, it means the script is modifying (generating requests), in a different frame.
So i just suppose the whole iframe was created by that script (other conditions are required, like the iframe url=="about:blank", etc)
I guess there are some cases where this supposition is false, but that's the closer i think i can get.